# which machine learning algorithm and tool to use for suggesting which bin(s) to use, and the quantity?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I am new and this is my first question here. I hope this is the right place to ask this.

I am looking for a machine learning tool and algorithm that I can use to suggest which bins to use and the quantity from each chosen bin. For example, demand for a particular item can be fulfilled by using any of the 4 bins (bin 1 ~ 4) and multiple bins can also be used. Based on the historical pattern, I'd like to suggest which bins to use and quantities as well. Here is a sample data. Given the Order quantity and initial quantities of the bins, I'd like to suggest which bin to use and how much (which are the 'used quantities').

| item | Order qty | packing_size | Initial qty |  |  |  | used qty |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | bin1 | bin2 | bin3 | bin4 | bin1 | bin2 | bin3 | bin4 |
| A | 500 | 20 | 150 | 350 | 100 | 250 | 100 | 150 | 100 | 150 |
| A | 100 | 20 | 80 | 10 | 50 | 10 | 40 | 10 | 40 | 10 |

Comment: Just to clarify: does `Initial qty` represents the maximum capacity of a bin?

Comment: I made a mistake putting the numbers while editing the table. Let me fix it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So for the first record, bin1 was initially 150, and 100 was used. The table does not show the remaining but it would be 50. I tried to make the data to show there are some pattern based on the order quantity and initial quantities of each bin. For example, when bin1 is used, same amount was used from bin3. There can be other patterns.